# How would I get the previous array items before X?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am creating a chat app and am displaying the last 10 submitted messages.

```
messages.last(10)
```

I would like to get the previous 15 messages before the 10 that are already displayed.

How would I do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the following:

```
messages[-25..-11]
```

See the following `irb` example

[image: irb example]

For better readability:

```
messages = [*0..30] # whatever way to obtain an array of messages
last_messages_amount = 10
previous_messages_amount = 15

previous_messages_range = -(last_messages_amount + previous_messages_amount)..-(last_messages_amount + 1)
previous_messages = messages[previous_messages_range]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can convert the messages into an enumerator if the slices of the same size (say, 10 messages).

```
messages_enum = messages.lazy.reverse_each.each_slice(10).map(&:reverse)

# Fetch the last 10 messages
p messages_enum.next

# Fetch 10 messages before the last 10 messages
p messages_enum.next

# Fetch 10 messages before the last 20 messages
p messages_enum.next
```

If there's nothing more to fetch, `messages_enum.next` will raise a `StopIteration`. You can handle it and tell the client there's nothing more.